# ionic: Navigate from ionic page to root (HomePage)

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm doing an ionic example: simple Notes app which let user add Note and display notes. When navigate from ionic page back to homepage I get this error:
[image]

This is the simple app:

[image: NOte list]

When press ADD from homepage, New Ionic page is displayed.

[image]

After user type Title and Content, then press Add one note will be added to the list and then app navigate back to homepage.
What I did is:
- Create add-note page.
- In add-note.ts, I navigate back to homepage like this:

```
addNote(note: Note){
this.noteListService.addNote(note).then(ref => {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
});
```

}

- in add-note.html I defined button like this:
  [image]

I did tried this.navCtrl.popToRoot() but it not work.

Anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

the flow should something like this. The app starts and the `HomePage` is loaded and displayed as `root`. When you navigate to another page you do `this.navCtrl.push(otherPage)`. When you want to go back to the root you do `this.navCtrl.pop()`

see [Ionic NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I fix this problem by:
- Import HomePage:

> import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home'

- setRoot(HomePage) instead of setRoot('HomePage'):

> this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);